# variable is not visible in eq selector

Tags: jquery

```
$('#ulLeft li').click(function () {
x = $(this).index();
change();
});  

function change(){
$('.cAct').removeClass().addClass('cPass');
alert (x);  //works fine
$('#ulLeft li:eq(x)').removeClass().addClass('cAct');  //doesn't work
}
```

In the last line `x` is not visible.
Changing `x` with some integer - works.
Any suggestion ?

Comment: Why do you expect a string containing the letter `x` to have special meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#ulLeft li:eq(' + x + ')').removeClass().addClass('cAct');
```

Since `x` is a variable, you need to check `:eq` against the value assigned to the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('#ulLeft li:eq('+x+')')` instead of `$('#ulLeft li:eq(x)')`

As `x` is a variable you need to use string concatenation

Or use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$('#ulLeft li').eq(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `concatenate` that variable `x` with the `string` to achieve what you needed.

Try,

```
$('#ulLeft li:eq('+ x +')').removeClass().addClass('cAct');
```

Or use [.eq(index)](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to do it with out concatenations.

```
$('#ulLeft li').eq(x).removeClass().addClass('cAct');
```